# Why is PPG signal not periodic?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I'm new to signal processing. I'm currently trying to convert the data retrieved from PPG to heart rate. I have a question about my PPG signal. So [This is the typical PPG signal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxSyo.png)

[At the same time, my signal looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YGXz.jpg)

[This is the signal after applying moving average filter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d54Q3.jpg)

[This is the signal after applying Savitzky-Golay filter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYAqg.jpg)

My signal is obtained from myself sitting still and putting my finger on a reflective PPG sensor with red light and infrared light. I didn't move my finger at all, so there should be no motion artifact, and there are around 53-55 samples in each second. I also extracted DC component from it, meaning extracting the mean from each data point. But why does my signal look so noisy? I tried moving average filter and savitzky-golay filter, but overall the shape is still not even close to the typical periodic PPG signal above. How can I make the shape of the signal more periodic? Are there any better filters I can try?

Comment: I've only worked with ECG, EEG and EMG signals so I can't give very precise advice here but are you sure there's no Band-pass filter needed? It's usually a fundamental phase in dealing with biological signals. Also approaching the cleaning of biological signals with no appropriate guide is usually very hard, I recommend you find a paper detailing the process and follow it.